# Auto-cleaning room (CIP for the ground?)

Tags: plumbing, pipe, cleaning, soil

In breweries, we used CIP (clean in place) to cleanin and sanitize vessel.

Here, I have a room (a production room for beverages) with slope on the ground and a gutter all room long because I have to clean it lot of times. Did you think it would be possible to make a water circuit with tiny hole on them in order to make the water flow on the whole room ground?

Did you already saw this? Do you think it could be made of too tricky?

Thank you

Comment: When you say water circuit, are you talking about a spray bar? I have seen spray bars maybe 3’ long with a wheel on each end that hooked to a hose it was a great water broom, I used that same idea and made one using air pressure for cleaning at my plant. Just about anything can be done with some thought and trial and error.

Comment: @EdBeal thank for answer. Yes, Kinda spray bar bur of 20'. A simple pipe with hole drilled could do the job you think?Thank for your feedback

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this has little to do with our site's topic; you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has little to do with "home improvement."

Comment: @DanielGriscom: Thank you. Making an auto-cleaning system for a room as a garage is definitively a home improvment topic for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning with water comes down to two things - pressure and volume.  Those are related, so to increase one, you have to decrease the other without something like a pressure pump to artificially increase the pressure of the system.

So, will it work?  Absolutely, but the water volume and spray pressure you get will be limited.  What I would do is buy some PVC pipe, and start drilling.  You can get 20' of pipe very cheaply, and it is easy to cut and drill.  Pick a small hole size, and space your holes every 2 feet.  Test it and see what happens.  If you have plenty of pressure, but want more water, drill more holes or re-drill the holes to the next largest size.

If you want to evenly coat the floor and don't really need pressure, then some sprinkler nozzles could be a very effective solution.  Once you have a hole or nozzle pattern that seems to work, you can replace the PVC with metal pipe if it needs to be more durable, but honestly, SCH40 PVC pipe is pretty strong.

What you want is not a "home improvement" idea.  It's more like adapting a commercial solution to the home, so you're going to have to build your own.  The trick is using materials that are cheap and easy to work with for prototyping along the way.

Comment: Thank you for the advices , I'll do this step by step as you recommand it